# Rails Data Pull in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I have a scatter chart in my Ruby on Rails app. I'm creating a point for every supplier that a company has. The sample company has just over 4,000 suppliers. I'm pulling the name of each supplier to use as the tooltip information. The issue is the db query is taking 16+ seconds. Is there a way to have the data pulled when I click on the point? Currently, all the data gets pulled into the chart and is available when a point is clicked. In the controller, I'm creating an array with x, y and supplier_id items:

```
SupplierScore.where(id: supplier_ids, company_specific: false)
  .group(:x, :y, :supplier_id)
  .order('count_id asc')
  .count(:id)
```

Also in the controller, I use the supplier_id to pull in all the suppliers (this happens in an `each` block):

```
data += "{x: #{array[0]}, y: #{array[1]}, marker: {radius: #{radius} }, supplier_name: `#{@suppliers.find_by(id: array[2]).name}` },"
```

Then, in the highcharts javascript, I show the supplier name when a point is clicked:

```
tooltip: {
  enabled: false,
  // show supplier name on tooltip
  formatter: function() {
    return this.point.supplier_name
  }
}
```

I also have my code setup to store only the supplier id instead of the supplier name (this is currently commented out):

```
data += "{x: #{array[0]}, y: #{array[1]}, marker: {radius: #{radius} }, supplier_id: #{array[2]} },"
```

I would like to retrieve the supplier name when the point is clicked using the supplier id that is stored in the array instead of retrieving all the supplier names when the array is created. I'm hopeful that this will cause the chart to load much faster.

**Edit:**

Here is the complete controller action:

```
def get_color_points(scores)
  total_count = scores.values.inject(0) { |sum, x| sum + x }

  data_1    = '['
  data_2 = '['

  scores.each do |array, count|
    radius = count / total_count.to_f * 300
    radius = radius < 5 ? 5 : radius
    radius = 5
    if array[1] <= 49
      # data_1 += "{x: #{array[0]}, y: #{array[1]}, marker: {radius: #{radius} }, supplier_id: #{array[2]} },"
      data_1 += "{x: #{array[0]}, y: #{array[1]}, marker: {radius: #{radius} }, supplier_name: `#{@suppliers.find_by(id: array[2]).name}` },"
    else
      # data_2 += "{x: #{array[0]}, y: #{array[1]}, marker: {radius: #{radius} }, supplier_id: #{array[2]} },"
      data_2 += "{x: #{array[0]}, y: #{array[1]}, marker: {radius: #{radius} }, supplier_name: `#{@suppliers.find_by(id: array[2]).name}` },"
    end
  end

  data_1 = orange_data[0, orange_data.length - 1] + ']'
  data_2 = turquoise_data[0, turquoise_data.length - 1] + ']'
  [data_1, data_2]
end
```

The resulting array looks like this (but with 4,000+ items):

```
[
  {x: 44, y: 15, marker: {radius: 5 }, supplier_id: 1792 },
  {x: 47, y: 14, marker: {radius: 5 }, supplier_id: 1816 },
  {x: 91, y: 7,  marker: {radius: 5 }, supplier_id: 3864 },
  {x: 82, y: 17, marker: {radius: 5 }, supplier_id: 1824 },
  {x: 78, y: 1,  marker: {radius: 5 }, supplier_id: 1888 },
  {x: 30, y: 7,  marker: {radius: 5 }, supplier_id: 3952 },
  {x: 77, y: 10, marker: {radius: 5 }, supplier_id: 1936 }
]
```

Comment: Can you show your controller action complete, so we can figure out the root cause ?

Comment: Hi @hashrocket, On frontend you should do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q78ef4h6/